# I want to Intent Pass from Fragment to Activity but My app crashes

Tags: android

i want to pass intent from fragment to activity but my app crashes
here  i am using onclick in card view

```
package com.example.dheryam;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class Home_fragment extends Fragment {
    public Home_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }
    public void paid_courses_clicked(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(),paid_courses.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code where you calling activity

Comment: @ShivamDohre in the question. And format it correctly so it is human-readable

Comment: Replace startActivity(intent) with activity().startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public void paid_courses_clicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity(),ClassName.class);
        requireActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

ClassName should be the class you want to go